# Numpy product or tensor product question

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, linear-algebra

How can I calculate this product without a loop? I think I need to use [`numpy.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) but I can't seem to set it up correctly. Here's the loop version:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,5,3,3)
b = np.random.rand(5,5,3,3)

c = np.zeros(a.shape[:2])
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    for j in range(c.shape[1]):
        c[i,j] = np.sum(a[i,j,:,:] * b[i,j,:,:])
```

(The result is a numpy array `c` of shape `(5,5)`)

Comment: Testing things with random would be a lot easier if you set the seed, and everyone could use the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've lost the plot. The answer is simply

```
c = a * b
c = np.sum(c,axis=3)
c = np.sum(c,axis=2)
```

or on one line

```
c = np.sum(np.sum(a*b,axis=2),axis=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you with the syntax ?

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = arange(60.).reshape(3,4,5)
>>> b = arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)
>>> c = tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))     # sum over the 1st and 2nd dimensions
>>> c.shape
(5,2)
>>> # A slower but equivalent way of computing the same:
>>> c = zeros((5,2))
>>> for i in range(5):
...   for j in range(2):
...     for k in range(3):
...       for n in range(4):
...         c[i,j] += a[k,n,i] * b[n,k,j]
...
```

(from http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-a46c9c520bd7a7b43e0ff166c01b57ec76eb96c7)